# What is the maximum hand size in Battlegrounds?

Tags: hearthstone

While playing as Arch-Villain Rafaam in Battlegrounds, his hero power is **I’ll Take That!: Next combat, add a plain copy of the first minion you kill to your hand.**

As you get later into the game where board space is a premium, you'd feel less inclined to play the cards from your hand. Or the ones you get don't have any synergy with your current build. But you want to hold onto them for the triple upgrades and the free tier upgrade that they provide.

Strategy aside of play the cards onto the empty space and selling for the coin; How many cards can you have in your hand?

Comment: I expect the answer is 10 cards, the same as every other mode in the game. I don't see a reason Hearthstone would have customized that limit for Battlegrounds.

Comment: Except when you have a card like this: https://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/151344-valdris-felgorge. I know it's a one off, but I haven't found anything concrete yet. Maybe I'll throw a run to test it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The maximum amount of cards to be held in a moment is 10. This was confirmed by Kripp in a Dancing Darryl run where he had already 10 cards and wanted to buy an extra one but couldn't. There might be some mechanics to cheat the game and hold more than 10, but this hasn't been found nor reported as of the moment of this writing. With Rafaam Kripp also had a similar problem and couldn't surpass the 10 cards limit.

I am working to find the links to Kripp's videos. Will update this answer as soon as I do.

### Edit:

Hysteria just published an interesting [video](https://youtu.be/fHFJUg-7ANY?t=90) where he tries to get over 10 cards by combining 2 golden Kadgars with Alleycat so that this spanws multiple Tabbycats, turning them into golden and forcing them into the players hand. When the player reaches 10 cards and new golden tabbycats are created, they simply vanish instead of going into the players hand (surpassing the 10 cards limit).